# Visual Studio 2008 DataList not visible

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, datalist, ascx

Im using VS 2008, and I am trying to a customize a DataList in an ascx file. The page has a SQLDataSource, a Datalist, and a very small amount of static text. When I edit the code in the .ascx page in the asp tag, say i'll add a `<div>` tag when I go back to Design mode the SqlDataSource, the DataList and both gone, but any static content I have is still on the page. Any changes That I do make will show up if I view the page in my browser. is causing this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering [here is a little article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2008/04/27/workaround-empty-design-view-for-user-controls.aspx) about this very topic I found.